# How to access Angular Material CdkDragPreview instance via injection token

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

In Angular Material's Drag and Drop there is an option to access the instances of the `CdkDragPreview`  This is the element that follows the mouse during a drag and drop operation and is essentially "dragged" by the user.

The logic in Material is to create the `DragPreview` a cloned version of the element that the drag is triggered on. This clone is then appended to the very end of the document body during a drag and drop operation. The cloned element is then removed again once the drop has been completed.

I would like to get a reference to that dragged element but I can't understand how. The Material docs state that [it can be accessed via an injection token](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CDK_DRAG_PREVIEW).

```
// Injection token that can be used to reference instances of CdkDragPreview. 
// It serves as alternative token to the actual CdkDragPreview class which 
// could cause unnecessary retention of the class and its directive metadata.

const CDK_DRAG_PREVIEW: InjectionToken<CdkDragPreview<any>>;
```

I don't understand how injection tokens work and I'm confuses as to when this token would even become available since, when the component constructor is called, the element is not even going to have been created yet.

**How can I use the injection token (as shown above) to access the drag preview instance?**

Comment: I don't think it's going to work since the preview is created by the drag element itself, but you can try using `@ViewChildren(CDK_DRAG_PREVIEW) dragPreview`

Comment: Thanks @YannickBeauchamp-H, unfortunately the preview is not added as a child to the current element - it's added to the document itself so it's not within scope of the component's `@ViewChildren`

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that the documentation you gave is supposed to be internal, in the sense that CDK_DRAG_PREVIEW should only be used when developing on the CDK's drag-n-drop feature.

I base my assumption on the source code itslef : as shown on [this page](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/directives/drag-preview.ts#L25), the injection token is only used as a provider in the Directive decorator, and unfortunately, the same decorator does not seem to have a `exportAs` property, which means you can't directly access it.

But depending on your needs, what you **CAN** access rather easily is your own template. [Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mvndz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-custom-preview-example.ts) (open the console to see it).

This only gives you access to the ElementRef (the HTML element that is used as the preview), not the actual drag preview directive though.